# Do plane projections determine a convex polytope?

Tags: convex-polytopes

Suppose a compact convex body $P \subset \Bbb R^3$ has only polygonal orthogonal projections onto a plane.  Does this imply that $P$ is a convex polytope?

This question occurred to me when I was making exercises for [my book](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~pak/book.htm).  I figured this is probably easy and well known, but the literature hasn't been any help.  One remark:  if the number of sides of all polygons is bounded by $n$, the problem might be easier.  Furthermore, if $P$ is *assumed* to be a convex polytope, [this](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~chazelle/pubs/ComplexityCuttingComplexes.pdf) elegant paper by Chazelle-Edelsbrunner-Guibas (1989) gives a (perhaps, unexpectedly large) sharp $\exp O(n \log n)$ upper bound on the number of vertices of $P$ (ht Csaba Toth who [generalized](http://math.ucalgary.ca/~cdtoth/cx-stabbing-rev.pdf) this to higher dimensions).

Comment: Suppose not.
By hypothesis, any finite intersection Q of supporting half-spaces of P strictly contains P. Because Q is a polytope, its orthogonal projections are polytopes. Let x be a point in Q\P. There is an orthogonal projection such that the image of x and that of P are disjoint. The corresponding polytope obtained by projecting Q strictly contains the projection of P. 


Comment: Let Q' be obtained by augmenting with supporting half-spaces such that the projections of Q and P coincide. By hypothesis, Q' still strictly contains P. By induction, we may therefore assume there is an infinite sequence of distinct points in Q that are not contained in P. Similarly, Q cannot be chosen so that all its orthogonal projections are the same as those of P. 


Comment: I am not sure I follow.  You assume that $P$ is not a polytope and you conclude with a property implying that $P$ is *really* not a polytope.  Now what?   

Comment: Let me make an easy general comment: any proof must use substantially the fact that this is a $3$-dim problem (it obviously fails in $\Bbb R^2$).  Also, use the fact that $P$ is bounded, since all projections of a circular cone are polyhedral cones.

Comment: I was originally thinking there might be some Bolzano-Weierstrassy thing that might reduce the problem, figured I'd comment since there's nothing else up here. The problem's considerably subtler than it appears at first.

Comment: There is a similar, but different, lemma in http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=733052 : If S is a subset of R^n such that the projection of S to 
every R^{d+1} is a union of finitely many d-dimensional polyhedra, then S is
a union of finitely many  d-dimensional polyhedra.

Comment: Thanks, David, I haven't seen this result.  Will take a look.  

Comment: @Igor: I haven't read it yet, but this preprint apparently gives a new short proof: http://arxiv.org/abs/1302.2354

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Theorem 4.1 of [this paper by Klee](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=105651) says yes.  Moreover, the result generalizes to higher dimensions for projections of arbitrary dimension $\ge 2$.

Comment: This is great!  Many thanks.  Let me read this paper carefully to understand what it really does and get back to you.  

Comment: After some thinking, it is now clear to me that what I wanted does easily follow from Klee. I am happy to accept this answer. Let me just mention that the key idea in Klee's paper is given in Mirkil's earlier paper http://www.cms.math.ca/cjm/v9/cjm1957v09.0001-0004.pdf, where the author proves that a closed convex cone is polyhedral if and only if all its 2-dim projections are closed and polyhedral (thus, circular cone doesn't work as it has a non-closed projection). Klee first refines and extends Mirkli's ideas, and then gives a "local" proof of the main result based on this.

Answer (score 13):

Here is a more direct proof of this statement.

[A Short Proof of Klee's Theorem](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1302.2354.pdf) by John J. Zanazzi